# FBXLoader doesn't load a fbx model 3d in three.js

Tags: three.js

Hello I'm trying to import an fbx model into my scene, but there is not much info on it online I had found one way that looks to use official three.js package but for some reason the model dose not appear in my scene, even through I don't get any errors. If any one can help me please because I have no clue at why it is not loading.

The guide that I used: https://sbcode.net/threejs/loaders-fbx/

The short version of the code.

```js
import { FBXLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/FBXLoader'

    const fbxLoader = new FBXLoader()
    fbxLoader.load('models/3dModdleOfTheBox.fbx', (object) => {
      scene.add(object)
    })
```

Full code

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'

import * as THREE from 'three'
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls'
import { FBXLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/FBXLoader'

export default function Threed_model() {
  //three js
  useEffect(() => {
    //basic setup
    const scene = new THREE.Scene()
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
      75,
      window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
      0.1,
      1000
    )
    camera.position.z = 5

    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      canvas: document.querySelector('#canvas'),
    })
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio)
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)

    //controls
    const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement)
    controls.enableZoom = false
    controls.enablePan = false
    controls.target.set(0, 0, 0)

    //fbx loader
    const material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial()
    const fbxLoader = new FBXLoader()
    fbxLoader.load('models/3dModdleOfTheBox.fbx', (object) => {
      scene.add(object)
    })

    //light
    const light = new THREE.PointLight()
    light.position.set(0.8, 1.4, 1.0)
    scene.add(light)

    const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight()
    scene.add(ambientLight)

    //adding stuff
    const geometry = new THREE.TorusGeometry(1, 0.5, 16, 100)

    const torus = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)

    scene.add(torus)

    function animate() {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate)
      renderer.render(scene, camera)
    }
    animate()

    renderer.render(scene, camera)
  }, [])
  return <canvas id="canvas">test</canvas>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out you have to set a scale for your model for it to display
`object.scale.set(0.01, 0.01, 0.01)`

My final code looked like this for who ever might need it.

```js
    fbxLoader.load('models/3dModdleOfTheBox.fbx', (object) => {
      object.traverse(function (child) {
        if (child.isMesh) {
          console.log(child.geometry.attributes.uv)

          const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(
            'models/pakage(12).png'
          )
          child.material.map = texture
          child.material.needsUpdate = true
        }
      })

      object.scale.set(0.01, 0.01, 0.01)
      scene.add(object)
      console.log(object)
    })
```